# Git repository using directory as externals

Tags: git, git-svn, git-submodules

I have an SVN repository with some documents using the same reference (bibtex) files via svn:externals. Its contents looks like this:

```
bibtex/
doc1/
-doc1.tex
-bibtex/ (svn:externals)
doc2/
-doc2.tex
-bibtex/ (svn:externals)
```

This way I could checkout each paper individually and obtaining the same reference. How can I setup the same with git?

I read that submodules were suggested, but if I try (after git svn clone)

```
git submodule add ./bibtex ./doc1/bibtex
```

I obtain

```
fatal: repository '/home/user/repo/bibtex' does not exist
Clone of '/home/user/repo/bibtex' into submodule path 'doc1/bibtex' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `bibtex` is in its own Git repository. Which is not how `svn external` is used, since it is a "relative external" link to a folder of the *same* repository.

Plus, after a `git svn clone`, you could reorganize your Git repo only if you do not intent to [`git svn dcommit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emdcommitem) back to the SVN repository.

If that is the case, then yes, you could:

- [split bibtext in its own repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository)
- push it to a new remote empty repo
- add it as submodule in your original repo

That is:

```
cd /path/to/svl-cloned/repo
cd doc1
git rm -r bibtex/
git commit -m "remove bibtex"
git submodule add /url/remote/bibtex/repo bibtex
git add .
git commit -m "Add bibtex submodule"
```